# Axios returns html data instead of json

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

In the `getInitialProps` function in Nextjs, I am trying to get a response from backend which is running inside a Kubernetes Container.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const buildClient = ({ req }) => {

  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // we are on the server
    console.log('getting executed in the server')
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local',
      headers: {
        ...req.headers,
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    instance.defaults.headers.get['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    return instance;
  } else {
    //  we must be on the browser
    console.log('getting executed in the browser')
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: '/'
    })
  }

};

export default buildClient;
```

this is how I am creating the axios instance

```
const client = buildClient(ctx);
console.log(client.defaults.headers);
```

gives

```
{
[client]   common: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' },
[client]   delete: {},
[client]   get: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
[client]   head: {},
[client]   post: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
[client]   put: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
[client]   patch: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
[client]   host: 'ticketing.dev',
[client]   'x-request-id': 'e38199c89b2b2584aac5480aed9a745b',
[client]   'x-real-ip': '192.168.49.1',
[client]   'x-forwarded-for': '192.168.49.1',
[client]   'x-forwarded-host': 'ticketing.dev',
[client]   'x-forwarded-port': '443',
[client]   'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
[client]   'x-forwarded-scheme': 'https',
[client]   'x-scheme': 'https',
[client]   'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
[client]   'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
[client]   'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
[client]   'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
[client]   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
[client]   accept: 'application/json',
[client]   'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
[client]   'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
[client]   'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
[client]   'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
[client]   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
[client]   'accept-language': 'en-IN,en;q=0.9',
[client]   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
[client] }
```

now

```
const res = await client.get('/api/tickets');
console.log(res.headers);
```

gives

```
AxiosHeaders {
[client]     server: 'openresty/1.13.6.1',
[client]     date: 'Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:44:12 GMT',
[client]     'content-type': 'text/html',
[client]     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
[client]     connection: 'close'
[client]   },
```

and when I console.log(res.data)
it gives a huge chunk of HTML data
notice that while building the axios instance I have set the headers to
headers: {
...req.headers,
accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
inside the console.log(res) object

```
request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
[client]     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
[client]       abort: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       connect: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       error: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       socket: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
[client]       finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
[client]     },
[client]     _eventsCount: 7,
[client]     _maxListeners: undefined,
[client]     outputData: [],
[client]     outputSize: 0,
[client]     writable: true,
[client]     destroyed: true,
[client]     _last: true,
[client]     chunkedEncoding: false,
[client]     shouldKeepAlive: false,
[client]     maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
[client]     _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[client]     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
[client]     sendDate: false,
[client]     _removedConnection: false,
[client]     _removedContLen: false,
[client]     _removedTE: false,
[client]     strictContentLength: false,
[client]     _contentLength: 0,
[client]     _hasBody: true,
[client]     _trailer: '',
[client]     finished: true,
[client]     _headerSent: true,
[client]     _closed: true,
[client]     socket: Socket {
[client]       connecting: false,
[client]       _hadError: false,
[client]       _parent: null,
[client]       _host: 'ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local',
[client]       _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
[client]       _readableState: [ReadableState],
[client]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[client]       _eventsCount: 6,
[client]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[client]       _writableState: [WritableState],
[client]       allowHalfOpen: false,
[client]       _sockname: null,
[client]       _pendingData: null,
[client]       _pendingEncoding: '',
[client]       server: null,
[client]       _server: null,
[client]       parser: null,
[client]       _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
[client]       [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 109151,
[client]       [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
[client]       [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
[client]       [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
[client]       [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
[client]       [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
[client]       [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
[client]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[client]       [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
[client]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
[client]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
[client]       [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 21665,
[client]       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 794
[client]     },
[client]     _header: 'GET /api/tickets HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
[client]       'Accept: application/json\r\n' +
[client]       'content-type: application/json\r\n' +
[client]       'host: ticketing.dev\r\n' +
[client]       'x-request-id: e38199c89b2b2584aac5480aed9a745b\r\n' +
[client]       'x-real-ip: 192.168.49.1\r\n' +
[client]       'x-forwarded-for: 192.168.49.1\r\n' +
[client]       'x-forwarded-host: ticketing.dev\r\n' +
[client]       'x-forwarded-port: 443\r\n' +
[client]       'x-forwarded-proto: https\r\n' +
[client]       'x-forwarded-scheme: https\r\n' +
[client]       'x-scheme: https\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"\r\n' +
[client]       'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\n' +
[client]       'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-fetch-site: none\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-fetch-mode: navigate\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-fetch-user: ?1\r\n' +
[client]       'sec-fetch-dest: document\r\n' +
[client]       'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
[client]       'accept-language: en-IN,en;q=0.9\r\n' +
[client]       'Connection: close\r\n' +
[client]       '\r\n',
[client]     _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
[client]     _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
[client]     agent: Agent {
[client]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[client]       _eventsCount: 2,
[client]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[client]       defaultPort: 80,
[client]       protocol: 'http:',
[client]       options: [Object: null prototype],
[client]       requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
[client]       sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
[client]       freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
[client]       keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
[client]       keepAlive: false,
[client]       maxSockets: Infinity,
[client]       maxFreeSockets: 256,
[client]       scheduling: 'lifo',
[client]       maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
[client]       totalSocketCount: 0,
[client]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[client]     },
```

Along with that as mentioned in [axios overriding defaults documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults) I have overridden the 'content-type' to 'application/json' yet in the res.headers the content-type is text/html.

I am confused if I am getting html response due to the headers that is provided or there is some wrong in the URL endpoint or api.

Answer (score 2):

The `Accept` header tells the server what type of data you will accept back.

The server may do any of three things with it:

- Use it to select the most appropriate data format for the resource you asked for and send it to you
- Respond with a [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) status code to tell you that it doesn't have that resource available in a format you accept
- Ignore it completely

Ignoring it completely is the default behaviour for most servers.

If you want to make the server respond with JSON (conditionally or not) then whomever can configure the server must configure the server to do so.

Comment: yes but the Accept header 'atleast' is set to application/json **everywhere**, now there are multiple places where request headers are visible as mentioned above, yet I am getting HTML response. I apologise I forgot to mention that the status code is 200. Also  the backend routers are **NOT GETTING TRIGGERED** at all.

Comment: @Vaibhav07 — Why "but"? Please read the paragraph immediately after the bulleted list. (If the backend routers aren't being triggered then perhaps you just got the URL wrong, which has nothing do with with the Accept header).